# Connected to VPN but still same IP

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I am trying to setup a VPN connection on my machine, Ubuntu 12.04. The steps I did are the following:

```
sudo pptpsetup --create myvpn --server 123.123.123.123 --username vpnuser --encrypt
sudo pon myvpn
```

After entering my password, I am succesfully connected to the VPN I guess: the output of /var/log/syslog:

```
Jan 28 13:23:11 mypc pppd[4368]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jan 28 13:23:11 mypc pppd[4368]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Jan 28 13:23:11 mypc pppd[4368]: local  IP address 172.20.x.x
Jan 28 13:23:11 mypc pppd[4368]: remote IP address 81.171.x.x
```

This is my `ifconfig` output:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:172.20.x.x  P-t-P:81.171.x.x  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1392  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:60 (60.0 B)  TX bytes:66 (66.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:4e:36:43:c8:8c  
          inet addr:192.168.x.x  Bcast:192.168.x.x  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e4e:36ff:fe43:c88c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15034 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24204707 (24.2 MB)  TX bytes:1892375 (1.8 MB)
```

So I guess at this point it all went well, but I still have the IP of my wireless network. I think I am missing the to route all the traffic through the vpn right ?

Comment: If you're connecting to a remote machine, I would say that this looks normal. The `ppp0` connection is showing the public IP's of your router and the remote machine for the VPN tunnel.

Comment: I want to be able to surf the web using the vpn connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to route your traffic through the tunnel, you must tell that to your operating system.
Please follow this link, at the official sf.net page. [howto](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/routing.phtml#all-to-tunnel)

Answer (score 1):

Please visit [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org) before you connect to the vpn. Write down, or keep the site open. It  should be your public WAN ip adress: 81.171.x.x
Then you connect your vpn, and visit [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org) again. Now the ip it shows should be like the address of the vpn server, in your example 123.123.123.123.

Comment: that is exactly what Im doing, the problem I think is that I need to redirect all the traffic trough the VPN connection. For the moment if I do this, I still see the same public wlan0 ip address.

Comment: I don't thikn wlan0 is equal to you public ip... It's you local ip,  that is not reachable via internet.

Comment: what I mean is, if I do exactly what you tell me to do, I see the same IP address, when I'm trying to use the IP address of the VPN.